# Hello, I want my embed message can be edited with my member and save it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make my embed message so that it can be edited with a member anytime. This way, they can add something to the list and save it, so when anyone type the command again it will show the edited embed. However, I'm not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}kos`) {
  if (
    message.member.roles.cache.has('712346176220954664') ||
    message.member.roles.cache.has('712346843849424926') ||
    message.member.roles.cache.has('712346899209781338')
  ) {
    let gato = message.guild.members.cache.find(
      (gato) => gato.id === '694488949980135444'
    );
    message.channel.send({
      embed: {
        color: 15158332,
        title: 'KOS List',
        description: 'This is the OS clan KOS!',
        fields: [
          {
            name: 'Clan KOS:',
            value: `
                    - All of TaCo clan
                    - All of REAL clan
                    - All of BBG2 clan
                    - Most of BFB clan
                    - Most of -GK- clan
                    - Most of * * * * clan
                     `,
          },
          {
            name: 'Player KOS:',
            value: `

                    - Neptune aka Galatea(-GK-)
                    - Jupiter (-GK-)
                    - NateFreezes (****)
                    - KidFlash (TaCo)
                    - Hiddeinnn (TaCo)| but he spares bossers
                    - 69Dot (VC)
                    - Asta (BFB)
                    - asui (-GK-)
                    - MAGEOfJUSTICE (TaCo)
                    - LegendsNeverDie4
                    - Gronun
                    - LXV (BBG2)
                    - Scrizen (BBG2)
                    - Kayan (BBG2)
                    - ooMINATOoo (BBG2)
                    - LIPER (sSs)
                    - ibss (BFB)
                    - Aelin (BFB)
                    - arrow000acenova (BBG2)
                    - Zuhaer (Ivy)

                    Dm <@${gato.user.id}> to update the list
                    Type \`${prefix}kos 2\` to open second page`,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think there is no such way, you could work with reactions or commands to alter the Embend but i dont think that there is a direct way to edit embeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.js provides a way to edit messages
`<Message>.edit(VALUE)`

If you record the message that you send
`const m = await message.channel.send(embed)`
you can do
`m.edit(embed)`

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the users to directly edit it, though you could use reactions. To edit the message, do

```
let sent = await message.channel.send(embed)
```

Then you could do

```
sent.edit(`poop`)
```

So it would edit the embed to say `poop`